# Parsec ignore everything except one fragment

Tags: html, haskell, parsec

I need to parse a single select tag in a poorly formed HTML document (so XML-based parsers don't work).

I think I know how to use parsec to parse the select tag once I get there, but how do I skip all the stuff before and after that tag?

Example:

```
<html>
   random content with lots of tags...
   <select id=something title="whatever"><option value=1 selected>1. First<option value=2>2. Second</select>
   more random content...
</html>
```

That's actually what the HTML looks like in the select tag. How would I do this with Parsec, or would you recommend I use a different library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
solution = (do {
  ; string "<tag-name"
  ; x <- ⟦insertOptionsParserHere⟧
  ; char '>'
  ; return x
  }) <|> (anyChar >> solution)
```

This will recursively consume characters until it meets a starting `<html>` tag, upon which it uses your parser, and leaves the recursion on consuming a final tag.

It is wise to note that there may be trailing whitespace before & after   To fix that, we could do this, providing your parser consumes the tags:

```
solution = ⟦insertHtmlParserHere⟧ <|> (anyChar >> solution)
```

To be clear that would mean that `⟦insertHtmlParserHere⟧` would have this kind of structure:

```
⟦insertHtmlParserHere⟧ = do
   string "<tag-name"
   ⋯
   char '>'
```

---

As a side-note, if you want to capture every tag available, you can quite happily use `many`:

```
everyTag = many solution
```

Comment: You mean `string "<option"` or `string "<select"` right? I don't care about the HTML tag itself, I care about the options inside that select tag.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess fixed, sorry about that!

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Now, a slight variation. I have a parser called `optionTag` that parses the inner option tags perfectly. How can I write: "parse this string, return a list of all option tags, and ignore the rest". Your method is great for matching one thing, but what about matching several things anywhere in the string?

Comment: What do you think about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549435/parsec-how-to-find-matches-within-a-string

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use regex and capture the select tag:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Regex.Posix


getOptionTags content = content =~ "(<select.*</select>)"::[[String]]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- readFile "in"
    putStrLn . show . head . head $ getOptionTags s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Replace.Megaparsec.findAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:findAll) to find the substrings in a document which match a parser.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec

let parseSelect :: Parsec Void String String
    parseSelect = do
        chunk "<select"
        manyTill anySingle $ chunk "</select>"
```

```hs
let input = "<html>\n   random content with lots of tags...\n   <select id=something title=\"whatever\"><option value=1 selected>1. First<option value=2>2. Second</select>\n   more random content...\n</html>"
```

```hs
>>> parseTest (findAll parseSelect) input
[Left "<html>\n   random content with lots of tags...\n   "
,Right "<select id=something title=\"whatever\"><option value=1 selected>1. First<option value=2>2. Second</select>"
,Left "\n   more random content...\n</html>"
]
```