# Parsec how to find "matches" within a string

Tags: haskell, parsec

How can I use parsec to parse all matched input in a string and discard the rest?

Example: I have a simple number parser, and I can find all the numbers if I know what separates them:

```
num :: Parser Int
num = read <$> many digit

parse (num `sepBy` space) "" "111 4 22"
```

But what if I don't know what is between the numbers?

```
"I will live to be 111 years <b>old</b> if I work out 4 days a week starting at 22."
```

`many anyChar` doesn't work as a separator, because it consumes everything.

So how can I get things that match an arbitrary parser surrounded by things I want to ignore?

---

**EDIT**: Note that in the real problem, my parser is more complicated:

```
optionTag :: Parser Fragment
optionTag = do
    string "<option"
    manyTill anyChar (string "value=")
    n <- many1 digit
    manyTill anyChar (char '>')
    chapterPrefix
    text <- many1 (noneOf "<>")
    return $ Option (read n) text
  where
    chapterPrefix = many digit >> char '.' >> many space
```

Comment: By the way, do you really need to choose Parsec for this task? Could you use a simple regular expression like `^<option.*value=(\d+).*>$`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an arbitrary parser `myParser`, it's quite easy:

```
solution = many (let one = myParser <|> (anyChar >> one) in one)
```

It might be clearer to write it this way:

```
solution = many loop
    where 
        loop = myParser <|> (anyChar >> loop)
```

Essentially, this defines a recursive parser (called `loop`) that will continue searching for the first thing that can be parsed by `myParser`. `many` will simply search exhaustively until failure, ie: EOF.

Comment: This answer is close, but you have to backtrack `myParser` if it consumes some input and fails, as @neil-smith notes in his answer. Also you have to consider if `myParser` succeeds without consuming any input, because then this will loop forever. [`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap) will handle these and other subtleties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 many ( noneOf "0123456789")
```

i'm not sure about "noneOf" and "digit" types but you can give e try also to

```
many $ noneOf digit
```

Comment: I guess you need to do it after you extract the <select> tag [using this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546940/parsec-ignore-everything-except-one-fragment).
There is no reason for using Parsec since you need just some values and you don't care at all about grammar.
Try use regex (i recommad tdfa) and extract your values. I can hepl you with the regex if you want to

Comment: That's very useful information. I wasn't sure if parsed was the right tool for this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is fine and dandy, but working for arbitrary parsers is more important in my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

To find the item in the string, the item is either at the start of the string, or consume one character and look for the item in the now-shorter string. If the item isn't right at the start of the string, you'll need to un-consume the characters used while looking for it, so you'll need a `try` block.

```
hasItem = prefixItem <* (many anyChar)
preafixItem = (try item) <|> (anyChar >> prefixItem)
item = <parser for your item here>
```

This code looks for just one occurrence of `item` in the string.

(AJFarmar almost has it.)

Answer (score 1):

The [replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec) package allows you to split up a string into sections which match your pattern and sections which don't match by using the [`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap) parser combinator.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

let num :: Parsec Void String Int
    num = read <$> many digitChar
```

```hs
>>> parseTest (sepCap num) "I will live to be 111 years <b>old</b> if I work out 4 days a week starting at 22."
[Left "I will live to be "
,Right 111
,Left " years <b>old</b> if I work out "
,Right 4
,Left " days a week starting at "
,Right 22
,Left "."
]
```