# non-greedy repetition with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec, non-greedy

I am trying to split my input into those parts that match a certain pattern and the rest, let's say

```
data Data = A Int | B Char | C String
parseDatas :: Parsec [Token] () a [Data]
```

I already have written two more-or-less complicated parsers

```
parseA :: Parsec [Token] () Data
parseB :: Parsec [Token] () Data
```

that match the things I am looking for. Now the obvious solution is

```
parseDatas = many (parseA <|> parseB <|> parseC)
```

where the parser for the intermediate parts would look like this:

```
makeC :: [Token] -> Data
makeC = C . concatMap show -- or something like this
parseC :: Parsec [Token] () Data
parseC = makeC <$> many anyToken
```

Meh, that throws a runtime `[ERROR] Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.` - ok, easily fixed:

```
parseC = makeC <$> many1 anyToken
```

But now `parseC` consumes the entire input (that starts with something I'm not looking for), ignoring any patterns that should yield an `A` or `B`!

**If my patterns were regexes**<sup>1</sup>**, I would now have changed the `+` operator to the non-greedy `+?` operator. How can I do the same for the `many1` parser combinator?**

<sub>1: which I cannot use, as I'm operating on tokens not characters</sub>

---

A solution I found was

```
parseC = makeC <$> many1 (notFollowedBy (parseA <|> parseB) >> anyToken)
```

but that does look, uh, *suboptimal*. It's not really generic. There must be something better.

I also had a look at [Parsec how to find "matches" within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29549435/1048572) where the suggestion was to define a recursive parser, but that looks like a hazzle if I don't want to drop the intermediate tokens and collect them in a list instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could let parseC consume exactly one token at a time:

`parseDatas = many $ parseA <|> parseB <|> (C . show <$> anyToken)`

and then, if you want, group adjacent `C`s into one to conserve semantics:

```
groupCs (C c) (C c':xs) = C (c ++ c') : xs
groupCs x xs = x : xs
parseDatas = foldr groupCs [] <$> many (parseA <|> parseB <|> (C . show <$> anyToken))
```

If you want to apply some operation `make :: [Token] -> String` on consecutive `C`s:

```
data Data c = A Int | B Char | C c deriving Functor

groupCs :: [Data a] -> [Data [a]] -> [Data [a]]
groupCs (C c) (C cs:xs) = C (c:cs) : xs
groupCs (C c) xs = C [c] : xs
groupCs x xs = x : xs

parseDatas = (map.fmap) make . foldr groupCs [] <$> many (parseA <|> parseB <|> (C <$> anyToken))
```

Comment: Hm, my problem is that I have to use `makeC` which takes a list of tokens. `makeC . return <$> anyToken` would work, but it looks ugly and just as inefficient as my current solution.

Comment: @Bergi, Here's how to make space to apply `make`. Further this way lay the `lens` library.

Comment: @Bergi Why do you believe `makeC . return <$> anyToken` is inefficient? It certainly won't be as inefficient as doing arbitrary lookahead as in your question.

Comment: I dunno, I guess I'd have to test. Performance is a bit unpredicable in Haskelll. It's just that the only function to convert tokens that is exposed by the library I am using takes this list of tokens, so I thought it should be called with a larger number of tokens. It's exact type is `[Token] -> Data.Text` if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the functor approach, I guess I can make that work.

Answer (score 1):

The
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap)
parser combinator from
[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
can split a string into those parts that match a certain pattern and the rest.

Try this:

```hs
sepCap (parseA <|> parseB)
```

Or, if `parseA` and `parseB` are parsers for different types of things, then maybe use [`eitherP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parser-combinators/docs/Control-Monad-Combinators.html#v:eitherP)
like:

```hs
sepCap (eitherP parseA parseB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, for the general question:

#### How do we repeat a “non-greedy” pattern?

…like in regex where we would repeat pattern `p` non-greedily by writing `p*?`?

The answer is:

#### `manyTill_ p q` where `q` is the entire rest of the parser.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parser-combinators/docs/Control-Monad-Combinators.html#v:manyTill_

Or, for `p+?`, it would be `someTill_ p q` where `q` is the entire rest of the parser.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parser-combinators/docs/Control-Monad-Combinators.html#v:someTill_